# Keyboard input in custom QQuickPaintedItem

Tags: c++, qt

I defined my custom QQuickPaintedItem in such a way:

```
class NiceItem : public QQuickPaintedItem
{

  ...

  public:

    ...

    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event);
    void paint(QPainter *painter);

  ...

};
```

Here you have `keyPressEvent`code:

```
void NiceItem::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event)
{

  if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Left)
    playerX--;
  else if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Right)
    playerX++;
  else if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Up)
    playerY--;
  else if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Down)
    playerY++;

}
```

Here's `paint` code:

```
void NiceItem::paint(QPainter *painter)
{

  QPen pen(m_color, 2);
  painter->setPen(pen);

  QRectF rectangle(playerX, playerY, 80.0, 60.0);
  painter->drawRect(rectangle);

  update();

}
```

As you can see code is really simple. Rectangle is successfully drawn on the screen, but pressing arrows does nothing. Is this a wrong method? If so, how can I process the keyboard input?

Answer (score 0):

For an Item to receive the mouse event, it must meet the following:

- Have the flag QQuickItem::ItemIsFocusScope enabled.
- Having focus, this can be done in C++ with `setFocus(true)` or in QML: `focus: true`.

On the other hand, if your objective is to draw a rectangle on the window, then you have an error in the concept of what coordinates are used for the painting, the painting uses the local coordinates and not the window or screen. So instead of creating new attributes you should only use `position()`, `x()`, `y()` (and their setters) to modify the geometry since these elements are with respect to the parent's coordinates.

```cpp
#ifndef NICEITEM_H
#define NICEITEM_H

#include <QQuickPaintedItem>

class NiceItem : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    NiceItem(QQuickItem *parent=nullptr);
    void paint(QPainter *painter);
protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
private:
    QColor m_color;
};

#endif // NICEITEM_H
```

```cpp
#include "niceitem.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QPen>

NiceItem::NiceItem(QQuickItem *parent):
    QQuickPaintedItem(parent), m_color(QColor("red"))
{
    setFlag(QQuickItem::ItemIsFocusScope, true);
    setFocus(true);
    setSize(QSizeF(80.0, 60.0));
}

void NiceItem::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    QPen pen(m_color, 2);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->drawRect(boundingRect());
}

void NiceItem::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    QPointF delta;
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Left)
        delta = QPointF(-1, 0);
    else if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Right)
        delta = QPointF(+1, 0);
    else if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Up)
        delta = QPointF(0, -1);
    else if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Down)
        delta = QPointF(0, +1);
    setPosition(position() + delta);
}
```

Comment: Still not working for me, I get keyReleaseEvent and all mouse events etc. and even keyPressEvent if I just hit a modifier key like Ctrl etc., but not any regular key.  I think it's something to do with how the application handles shortcut keys (QQuickShortcut::event is trapping it instead, but I don't know how).

Comment: In the end I had to override event() and look for ShortcutOverride events.